# How to check CSS media query with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, media-queries, screen-resolution

on the following url:

https://gist.github.com/marcedwards/3446599

I found the following CSS code to check high DPI screens.

```
@media
    only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.3),
    only screen and (-o-min-device-pixel-ratio: 13/10),
    only screen and (min-resolution: 120dpi) {
    /* Your code to swap higher DPI images */

}
```

This code is based on:

https://bjango.com/articles/min-device-pixel-ratio/

**My question is:** Is there any way to create a flag (true/false) based on if above conditions are meet or not?

**My goal is:** I have a set of images: `<img src="..." />` where depending on the screen resolution (above condition meets or not) I wanna use one image or other.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you asking if you can check device pixel ratio is above 1 or not using js? It is possible to set a flag in css and detect it with js. I would prefer you clarify exactly what you are after in what language first

Comment: I don't think this way would be the best way, but you could give the element for example `opacity: 1` when that media query requirement is met. And check with javascript if the style of element `a{ }` equals `opacity = 1`

Comment: `window.devicePixelRatio`

Comment: My goal is: I have a set of images: <img src="..." /> where depending on the screen resolution (above condition meets or not) I wanna use one image or other.

Comment: @davidesp I Imagine you want to use a bigger image for a dense screen so the image appears crystal clear, then you can use srcset on the image tag which requires no js https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Multimedia_and_embedding/Responsive_images

Comment: `srcset` attribute is your best bet, be aware though that it doesn't work in Internet Explorer

Comment: There is a flip side to this coin, some people avoid using srcset because it always grabs the bigger image on the phone for pixel ratio > 1. They avoid using it because they want to serve the smaller/normal image meant to be used on the phone. in other words, they don't want users downloading large images on their phones, also helps the page to load faster assuming the images have no loading framework

Comment: anyway, I think `srcset` is the way, thanks for your help

Comment: Re your original question: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/matchMedia

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Huangism and @phuzi pointed out, the way is to use: [`srcset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/img#attr-srcset).
The only caveat about this is it is not supported by IE yet (as of today).

Answer (score 0):

Could use some temporary element with a class to change on media query trigger to test:

HTML:

```
<p class="my-flag">Did the media query trigger?</p>
```

CSS:

```
@media
    only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.3),
    only screen and (-o-min-device-pixel-ratio: 13/10),
    only screen and (min-resolution: 120dpi) {
    /* Your code to swap higher DPI images */

.my-flag {
   color: red;
 }
}
```

And if you need this check in JS just ask

```
if($('.my-flag').style.color == "red")) {
     /* do stuff */ 
}
```

Comment: My goal is: I have a set of images: <img src="..." /> where depending on the screen resolution (above condition meets or not) I wanna use one image or other.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [window.matchMedia()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/matchMedia) for media queries in javascript.

```
if (window.matchMedia("(min-width:640px)").matches) {
    // mathes
} else {
    // not mathes
}
```